# Batch I want input %Something% in %Something%

Tags: batch-file, input, set

I want to input Valiable %%

```
set something=something

set test=test

set test2=%test:something=%
```

but `set test2=%test:%something%=%` <- wrong...

how input something...

Comment: @chiwangc why did you put the asterisks in there.  Leading asterisks have special meaning in the SET command.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for pointing out, I have fixed the formatting

Comment: Your examples will do nothing.  The value of your variable %something% is not in the value of the variable %test%, so %test% will never change and %test2% will just equal %test%.  Regardless of the poor example you would have to use delayed expansion with the %test% variable or use the CALL set method that Magoo explained below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably

```
call set "test2=%%test:%something%=%%"
```

but without an example, it's hard to tell.